# Set proxy to auto in Linux Mint

Tags: linux, proxy, linux-mint

I need to set a system wide proxy setting to automatically search the proxy settings like it's possible in windows.
I use Linux Mint Xfce and don't find any place in the GUI where I'm able to set my proxy settings. I'd also use a terminal to configure some proxy config files if there are any.

Important is, that the proxy settings apply to browsers (chromium, firefox) and apt-get (which also uses http, right?) and are set to auto search for proxy.

**Edit:**
I know about the http_proxy, ftp_proxy etc. variables. But I don't know yet how to configure my system to autodiscover proxy settings.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a script file under /etc/profile.d/10-proxy.sh

---

```
proxyserver=http://USERNAME:PASS@HOST:PORT
export http_proxy=$proxyserver
export ftp_proxy=$proxyserver
```

---

2. chmod +x 10-proxy.sh
3. after reboot/relogin the settings are systemwide

Comment: thanks for the idea to create a proxy script. But I do also need to autodiscover proxy settings.

Comment: Only way to autodiscover the proxy is WPAD or a PAC file.
If you use DHCP and the environment is correctly set up, you could read the proxy option from /var/lib/dhclient/dhclient-XXXX.lease | /var/lib/dhcpcd/*.lease .
If the enviroment use fixed client ips you should check if a PAC file is used.

Answer (score 1):

All of these tools should honor the `http_proxy` environment variable. Just set it in your profile script. Like this:

```
http_proxy=http://username:password@host:port/
export http_proxy
```

Comment: Sadly, there's no profile script. I don't know the proxy ip and port. In windows it's possible to automatically discover the proxy settings without script. Is that possible in linux?

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at "auto-apt-proxy" which is available in debian / ubuntu package repositories together with `Acquire::http::ProxyAutoDetect` in the apt settings.

Also see https://askubuntu.com/questions/53443/how-do-i-ignore-a-proxy-if-not-available